# RxJS - issue with .map() and .subscribe()

Tags: json, angular, rxjs

I am getting error when using `.map()` and `.subscribe()` of `RxJS` in `angular2`. Please find below code of `app.component.ts`.

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Injectable, Observable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu',
    templateUrl: 'app/app-menu.html'
})

export class AppComponent {  
    result: Object;     
    error: Object;
    http: Http; 

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
        this.loadFriendsSuccessFully();         
    }

    loadFriendsSuccessFully(){      
        this.http.get('app/menu.json')
                      .map(res => res.json())
                      .subscribe(
                        data => this.result = data,
                        err => console.log('ERROR!!!'),
                        () => console.log('Got response from API', this.result)
                      );

    }

}
```

Here `menu.json` file is loaded successfully which means `angular2` `http` is working fine but I am not able to bind `json` values to template.

`menu.json`

```
[
  {
    name: 'Home',
    icon: 'app/images/menu-item.svg'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cell',
    icon: 'app/images/menu-item.svg'
  },
  {
    name: 'Office',
    icon: 'app/images/menu-item.svg'
  }
]
```

Below is the error:

```
ERROR!!! SyntaxError: Unexpected token n
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Function.Json.parse (http://localhost:3000/app/lib/angular2.dev.js:357:27)
    at Response.json (http://localhost:3000/app/lib/http.dev.js:282:36)
    at MapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.ts!transpiled:31:58)
    at MapSubscriber.tryCatcher (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js:7002:29)
    at MapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js:3930:54)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js:9500:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.baseResponseOptions.response.Observable_1.Observable.onLoad (http://localhost:3000/app/lib/http.dev.js:652:30)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/app/lib/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
    at Zone.NgZone._createInnerZone.zone.fork.fork.$run [as run] (http://localhost:3000/app/lib/angular2.dev.js:5719:32)
```

using `es6-shim: v0.33.13`,
`angular2-polyfills.js`,
`SystemJS v0.19.6`,
`typescript 1.7.3`,
`Rx.js`,
`angular2.dev.js`,
`http.dev.js`

**What could be the issue here with `.map()` and `.subscribe()` ?**

Comment: And what is the error?..

Comment: @dfsq- added error message.

Comment: This looks like a malformatted JSON. Try jsonlint.com

Comment: @Pierre- yes actually I validated JSON but quotes are missing in key and I  replace single quote with double in value as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this was in my answer below :) @ChakoDesai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look related to RxJS.. Your JSON is malformed. Try adding double quotes around prop names and values:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Home",
    "icon": "app/images/menu-item.svg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Cell",
    "icon": "app/images/menu-item.svg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Office",
    "icon": "app/images/menu-item.svg"
  }
]
```

The JSON parser breaks when trying to parse `name`, therefore the `Unexpected token n` in the error.